# How to send GPT response from ExpressJS to ReactJS in streaming data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to send data of OpenAI GPT API from ExpressJS server to ReactJS, I checked multiple article like this one [OpenAI Completion Stream with Node.js and Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137987/openai-completion-stream-with-node-js-and-express-js) but none of them worked I get the prompt from ReactJS.

```
app.post('/gpt', (req, res) => {
 // let's assume here req.body
    (async function openAiApi() {

     const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
                model: "gpt-4",
                messages: [{

                     role: "user", content: "write a 100 word paragraph about tourism"
                }],
                stream: true,
            }, { responseType: 'stream' });
    
            for await (const chunk of stream) {
    
                console.log(chunk.choices[0].delta.content) // here I get stream data 
                var readStream = chunk.choices[0].delta.content; // 
                readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    res.write(chunk);
                })
                    .on('error', (err_msg) => {
                        console.log(err_msg);
                        res.end(err_msg);
                    })
                    .on('end', () => {
                        res.end();
                    });
            }

    }());

})
```